# Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2^k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

What is the method finding the closed form of $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2^k}$?

Comment: You can use summation by parts.

Comment: Don't look for "the" method; look for "a" method. You'll probably never find a math problem for which there is only one method of solving it. $\qquad$